# Custom URL field with Unique constraint deployment issue

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, validation

I have custom field `URL__c` in my sandbox that is of `Type: URL` and with a unique constraint. This field was previously a **Text** type field when I put the **unique** constraint to this field and later I changed the field type to **URL** as this field will be holding the URLs (so I thought it would be right to change it to type:URL)(screenshot attached below)

[image]

If I check the metadata of the object in force.com IDE it has no information related to the unique constraint.

```
<fields>
    <fullName>URL__c</fullName>
    <description>HTTP URL of the article/video.</description>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>URL</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Url</type>
</fields>
```

Is this a bug? Because, Salesforce doesn't support creating a **URL** type fields with unique constraint. I want to make this field unique so the end-users don't create the records for the same URL more than once.

> **Now the PROBLEM:**

When I deployed a changeset to another sandbox of mine, the URL field is no more a **Unique** constraint field, what are the suggestions? Should I change the field type to **text**? or should I delete the current field and create another field with type **text** with Unique constraint? What would be the best/efficient way of holding URL (with Unique constraint) in the system?

Comment: does adding constraint `Unique` allows to store only unique records?

Comment: Yes,  it does create unique records.

Comment: Strange. I guess you found a bug then.